# How to delete meta data from .exe file with cmd

Tags: cmd, metadata, administrator

I want to delete meta data from .exe file, im Administrator whem im trying to delete the data through Details->Remove properties... -> Remove the following.. -> select what i want to delete(date for example) -> ok. 
but, i get error  that im not administrator, but im.
is there another way to delete the meta data like cmd or another way?

Comment: It does not seem possible to remove/delete the VERSIONINFO structure from a .exe file. What is the use case? Why would this need to be done? It may be possible to overwrite the VERSIONINFO structure. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Add-FileVersion-Property-8586449e

Comment: CreationTime, LastAccesTime, LastWriteTime are managed by the OS/FileSystem and can't be deleted - just changed. There are ports of Unix/Linux Touch or use J-/vbscript and a FileSystemObject or PowerShell to modify these dates.

Comment: `Copy` command is overloaded with touch features.     `,` used with copy to indicate missing parameters. This updates the files 
    modified date. E.G. `copy /b file1,,`

Answer (score 0):

Meta data in windows is a very broad field.

Aside from CreationTime, LastAccesTime, LastWriteTime the exe file information is contained in the PE file header and build on compile/link time. It could/should IMO only be changed by the author/programmer. Every decent HEX file editor could change it but possibly breaking crc/hash codes that way.